# REGEXP_REPLACE Punctuation in Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to remove all punctuation from a `varchar`. I'm using the following:

```
regexp_replace(d.NAME, [.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()])
```

But it gives me an error, saying:

> Statement 1 is not valid. ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

How can I fix this to remove all punctuation?

Comment: `regexp_replace(d.NAME,'[^a-zA-Z]','')`?

Comment: @vkp That would also replace whitespace, numbers, and letters like `ñ`. That's not acceptable in most cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, the dash in a character class means a *range*, except when it's first or last... so put it there:

```
[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\_`~()-]
```

And, you have to put it in quotes, and most characters don't need escaping:

```
regexp_replace(d.NAME, '[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, my friend. There don't seem to be many good resources on regex...what's your go-to source?

Comment: The site [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) is my go-to for any regex testing -- I can't recommend it enough.